# Remove duplicates from list of strings

Tags: python

Ok so I have a list like this, what I need is to remove the duplicate values so that I end up with just- Joe Blow, Don Wiliams, Clark Gordon... 
Im trying this code which does not seem to work. I also tried to conver the list into a set but no go.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

```
dupes = ["Joe Joe Joe Blow","Don Don Williams", "Clark Clark Gordon", "Albert Riddle"]
def remove_duplicates(dupes):
    ulist = []
    [ulist.append(x) for x in dupes if x not in ulist]    
    return ulist
a=' '.join(remove_duplicates(dupes))

print(a)
```

Comment: `[ulist.append(x) for x in dupes if x not in ulist]` do **not** use list comprehensions for side-effects! List comprehensions are *not* just "in-line" for loops.

Answer (score 5):

Turn your string into a list, cast it into a set, then join it back with ' '. When casting to a set, preserve order by sorting by the index of the original string.

```
for s in dupes:
    print(' '.join(sorted(set(s.split()), key=s.index)))
```

output:

```
Joe Blow
Don Williams
Clark Gordon
Albert Riddle
```

Edit: If you want to alter the list in place:

```
def remove_duplicates(dupes):
    for i in range(len(dupes)):
        dupes[i] = ' '.join(sorted(set(dupes[i].split()), key=dupes[i].index))
```

Comment: Very nice solution to the ordering problem!

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's handled (very nicely btw) with `sorted` and the `key=s.index` - one improvement would be to give solution as a list comprehension

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I realized as soon as I posted and subsequently edited with sorting the set.

Comment: Yep -removed the comment ;) and +1 - it is rather neat

Comment: Keep in mind that sorting requires an average time complexity of *O(n log n)*, while the problem of removing dupes could be solved in *O(n)* with other methods.

Answer (score 1):

The long but stable way:

```
dupes = ["Joe Joe Joe Blow","Don Don Williams", "Clark Clark Gordon", "Albert Riddle"]

rv = [[]]
for d in dupes:
    seen = set()
    for e in d.split():         # split each string into its name, add the name to the 
        if e not in seen:       # last list in rv and to the set 'seen' that remembers
            rv[-1].append(e)    # the seen ones.
            seen.add(e)
    rv[-1] = ' '.join(rv[-1])   # done with one name, replace the list with joined values
    rv.append([])               # and append an empty, new list for the next name

dupes = [k for k in rv if k]    # remove the empty list at the end and overwrite dupes

print(dupes)
```

Output:

```
['Joe Blow', 'Don Williams', 'Clark Gordon', 'Albert Riddle']
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick! It's thowing a     for e in d.split():         # split each string into its name, add the name to the 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment how can I fix it

Comment: @RobD nice - lets delete the comments then

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re.sub` method to replace repetitions to a word with just the word:

```
import re
def remove_duplicates(string):
    return re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b(?:\s+\1)+', r'\1', string)
```

so that:

```
[remove_duplicates(dupe) for dupe in dupes]
```

returns:

```
['Joe Blow', 'Don Williams', 'Clark Gordon', 'Albert Riddle']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
def remove_duplicates(string):
    return ' '.join(k for k, _ in groupby(string.split()))
```

so that:

```
[remove_duplicates(dupe) for dupe in dupes]
```

returns:

```
['Joe Blow', 'Don Williams', 'Clark Gordon', 'Albert Riddle']
```

Answer (score 0):

When order is important [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) comes in handy:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dupes = ["Joe Joe Joe Blow", "Don Don Williams", "Clark Clark Gordon", "Albert Riddle"]
result = [' '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(w.split())) for w in dupes]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Joe Blow', 'Don Williams', 'Clark Gordon', 'Albert Riddle']
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers already, you can also try Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

counters = [Counter(d.split()) for d in dupes]
final = [' '.join(c.keys()) for c in counters]

# ['Joe Blow', 'Don Williams', 'Clark Gordon', 'Albert Riddle']
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use set which

```
  list(set(l)) 
  # where l is your str
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.